# Need help on retriving data from mySQL database and displaying it in input type=list as a dropdown list using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, dropdown

Guys following is my html code.

```
<form method="post">
     <table class="table-entry" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="team" id="team" value="Team:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td>
             <input list="tm" name="teamv" id="teamv" placeholder="Team" />
                <datalist id="tm">
                <option value="Pre-press"></option>
                <option value="eBooks"></option>
                </datalist>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="prno" id="prno" value="Project No.:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td>
             <input list="prct" name="prjctv" id="prjctv" placeholder="Project Number" />
                <datalist id="prct">
                <option value="Project001"></option>
                <option value="Project002"></option>
                </datalist>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="isbn" id="isbn" value="ISBN:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="number" name="isbnv" id="isbnv" maxlength="13" placeholder="ISBN" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="eisbn" id="eisbn" value="eISBN:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="number" name="eisbnv" id="eisbnv" maxlength="13" placeholder="eISBN" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="title" id="title" value="Title:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="titlev" id="titlev" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="on" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="authr" id="authr" value="Author:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="authrv" id="authrv" placeholder="Author" autocomplete="on" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="publr" id="publr" value="Publisher:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="publrv" id="publrv" placeholder="Publisher" autocomplete="on" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="page" id="page" value="Pages:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="number" name="pagev" id="pagev" placeholder="Pages" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="scope" id="scope" value="Scope:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td>
             <input list="scp" name="scopev" id="scopev" placeholder="Scope" />
                <datalist id="scp">
                <option value="PDF to ePub"></option>
                <option value="PDF to PRC"></option>
                </datalist>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="process" id="process" value="Process:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td>
             <input list="prcs" name="processv" id="processv" placeholder="Process" />
                <datalist id="prcs">
                <option value="Reflow"></option>
                <option value="Fixed"></option>
                </datalist>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="complx" id="complx" value="Complexity:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td>
             <input list="cmplx" name="complxv" id="complxv" placeholder="Complexity" />
                <datalist id="cmplx">
                <option value="Light"></option>
                <option value="Simple"></option>
                <option value="Medium"></option>
                <option value="Complex"></option>
                <option value="Heavy Complex"></option>
                <option value="Custom"></option>
                </datalist>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="recdte" id="recdte" value="Received Date:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="date" id="recdtev" name="recdtev" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="cnfdte" id="cnfdte" value="Confirm Date:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="date" id="cnfdtev" name="cnfdtev" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="duedte" id="duedte" value="Due Date:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="date" id="duedtev" name="duedtev" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="esthr" id="esthr" value="Estimated Hours:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="esthrv" id="esthrv" placeholder="Estimated Hrs" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="manpwr" id="manpwr" value="Man Power:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="number" name="manpwrv" id="manpwrv" placeholder="Manpower" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="label" name="dlvrydte" id="dlvrydte" value="Delivery Date:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="date" id="dlvrydtev" name="dlvrydtev" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add" /></td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
     </form>
```

Now what i need is, to display the data stored in database, in their respective fields based the option selected first.
Example:

```
<tr>
     <td><input type="label" name="team" id="team" value="Team:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
     <td>
     <input list="tm" name="teamv" id="teamv" placeholder="Team" />
        <datalist id="tm">
        <option value="Pre-press"></option>
        <option value="eBooks"></option>
        </datalist>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><input type="label" name="prno" id="prno" value="Project No.:" readonly="readonly" /></td>
     <td>
     <input list="prct" name="prjctv" id="prjctv" placeholder="Project Number" />
        <datalist id="prct">
        <option value="Project001"></option>
        <option value="Project002"></option>
        </datalist>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

In above code if am selecting any one of the team i.e either pre-press or ebooks, the project number relevant to the team should be listed from the database instead of giving it like this:

```
<input list="prct" name="prjctv" id="prjctv" placeholder="Project Number" />
    <datalist id="prct">
    <option value="Project001"></option>
    <option value="Project002"></option>
    </datalist>
```

Can someone help me with this. i've already tried some methods but of no use.

Guys if cant understand a question just ask for clarification, don't just put the question on hold.

Thought this would be best for newbies but its not. If am genius to find the solution why hell should i need help from people out there.

Am really very disappointed.

Comment: You want someone to write a query for you?

Comment: Either i need a method or the query itself. I need a solution for this thats all. @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: you have to use jquery ajax with php

Comment: this is totally a mess can u plz explain what exactly you want

Comment: *I need a solution for this thats all.* well bad news for you will not get any solution, the only solution you will get is by checking tutorials on how to select from mysql @Elson

Comment: what i need is that instead of giving datalist manually i want data to be retrieved from the database itself. And also only the data based on selected option should loaded in respective input fields i.e data should be filtered based on previous selections @KishanOza

Comment: Retrieving data from MySQL and using that data to create an HTML element is MySQL/PHP 101. Please take the time to find some tutorails and work through them.

Comment: Am working on it @lalithkumar

Comment: **SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: "Guys if cant understand a question just ask for clarification" It looks like ppl understood the question, they mostly were not prepared to help because the question is clearly off-topic (for SO anywa, maybe not elsewhere) and because you clearly hadn't done even some basic research and hoped someone would just do your work for you. This is a problem-solving forum, not a free consultancy. If you'd already done any work on this or tried it, as you claimed, then you should have shared it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First you need to get the data from the database. Here a doc regarding pdo: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

then, set the attribute seleted of your option if it is the same as in the database:

```
<input list="prct" name="prjctv" id="prjctv" placeholder="Project Number" />
    <datalist id="prct">
    <option value="Project001" <?php echo $databasevalue == "Project001" ? 'selected=true':""; ?>></option>
    <option value="Project002" <?php echo $databasevalue == "Project002" ? 'selected=true':""; ?>></option>
    </datalist>
```

Inline not the nice way, but it does the trick and shows the idea